# Skip the empty value inside a list

Tags: python

I found a problem on append the list of the first, second, until n index. It works fine until I found out that one of the list inside the nested list there are empty value/not the same length

Let say I have a nested list

```
A = [['1 2 3 4 5'],['9 8 7 6 5 4'],['1'],['3 4 5 6']

new = []

for i in range(0,(len(A))):
    new.append(A[i][0].split(' ')[2]) # 2 here is the index that i want to take

new
# output
[1,9,1,3] # first index
[2,8,4] # second index supposed to be
[3,7,5] # third index supposed to be
```

The error is IndexError: list index out of range
How to skip the empty value or if the index not present?

Comment: You can check the length before appending. `splitted = A[i][0]; if len(splitted)>2:`

Comment: Do you want your result to be int or strings? Why does `A` contain one-element lists of strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use try and except to do this. For example:

```
A = [['1 2 3 4 5'],['9 8 7 6 5 4'],['1'],['3 4 5 6']]

new = []

for i in range(0,(len(A))):
    try:
        new.append(A[i][0].split(' ')[2]) 
    except IndexError:
        continue

print(new)
# Output: ['3', '7', '5']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the below, using index in order to check the length of the string:

```
index = 0
for elem in A:
    if(len(elem[0])>index):
        new.append(elem[0].split(' ')[index])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this logic:

```
A = [['1 2 3 4 5'],['9 8 7 6 5 4'],['1'],['3 4 5 6']]

max_sub_length = max([len(i[0].split()) for i in A])
new = []
A_ = [ele[0].split() for ele in A]
for i in range(max_sub_length):
    tmp = [int(ele[i]) for ele in A_ if len(ele) > i]
    new.append(tmp)

print(new)
```

output is:

```
[[1, 9, 1, 3], [2, 8, 4], [3, 7, 5], [4, 6, 6], [5, 5], [4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) and remove the `None`s:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

A = [['1 2 3 4 5'],['9 8 7 6 5 4'],['1'],['3 4 5 6']]

sA = (x[0].split() for x in A) # splitting generator
new = [[int(y) for y in x if y is not None] for x in zip_longest(*sA)]
# [[1, 9, 1, 3], [2, 8, 4], [3, 7, 5], [4, 6, 6], [5, 5], [4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, one liner:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
result = [list(filter(None, i)) for i in zip_longest(*[i[0].split(' ') for i in A])]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check the length of the list. Please note that the index starts from `0`. i.e. the `[2,8,4]` you are aiming at is of index `[1]`.
A simple way to make it work:

```py
for i in range(0,(len(A))):
    one_list = A[i][0].split(' ')
    if len(one_list)> 1:
        new.append(one_list[1])
```

However, please ask yourself whether you. want to "miss" the missing element, or you'd rather fill this gap. E.g.

```py
for i in range(0,(len(A))):
    one_list = A[i][0].split(' ')
    if len(one_list)> 1:
        new.append(one_list[1])
    else: new.append(' ')
```

Where your vector will be either `['2', '8', '4']` or `['2', '8', ' ', '4']`

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this problem because the 3rd element of your list `['1']` is only a single element and in your loop, as you can see `new.append(A[i][0].split(' ')[2])` referring to the 3rd element of the list. So That is why you are getting this error.

You can either use a try block to solve this:

```
 for i in range(0,(len(A))):
     try:
         new.append(A[i][0].split(' ')[2])
     except IndexError:
         continue
```

or you can simply use a conditional block:

```
for i in range(0,(len(A))):
    if len(i) >= 3:
        new.append(A[i][0].split(' ')[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A = [['1 2 3 4 5'],['9 8 7 6 5 4'],['1'],['3 4 5 6']]
new = []

a_value = [i[0].split() for i in A] # split
max_len = max([len(a) for a in a_value]) # max val in a list

for i in range(max_len):
    new.append([int(j[i]) for j in a_value if len(j) > i])
print(new)
```

Answer

```
[[1, 9, 1, 3], [2, 8, 4], [3, 7, 5], [4, 6, 6], [5, 5], [4]]
[Finished in 0.5s]
```